# webiview :webpage design changed in Android

Tags: javascript, android, css, android-layout, webview

i have try to load the web page in android webview,that page consist lot of input fields,this page is working fine in all browsers in windows,in android the page is loaded properly with web view the problem is when ever in invoke the keyboard from from text field the text box is duplicated that means anothe text box is shown in that same page after i entered that value it get normal placed..[image: this is how my page look before invoking keyboard]

Pic1 shows  how my page look before invoking keyboard

pic 2 shows how it shows after keyboard comes

[image]

i cant find where is problem lies on , this was normal html with css .could any facin this problem before in android.

Comment: Try refreshing after deleting your cache/cookies.

Comment: no i got this issue every time.even first time also

Comment: try this `mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: i have used following Browser.requestFocusFromTouch();

     WebSettings settings = Browser.getSettings();  
     settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
     settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
     
     settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
     settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this in `CSS`:

```
input[type="password"], input[type="text"]{
    position: relative;
    top: -10000px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10000px, 0);
}
```